# JSON data, and the URL for the Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, jsonp

Good evening everyone,

I'm trying to retrieve JSON data via the World of Warcraft Community API.  I have a functioning program that retrieves all the data from the URL in the following code snippet, and it does in fact alert my character name.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Wreckedified Raiding</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                "url":"http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/aerie-peak/Eldershield?jsonp=myCallback",
                "type":"GET",
                "dataType":"jsonp",
                "contentType":"application/json",
                "jsonpCallback":"myCallback",
                "success":function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data.name);
                }               
            })
            alert("Hello World!");
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

However, the data I really want is in JSON format at the following URL:

http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/aerie-peak/Eldershield?fields=items

My question is this:  How am I supposed to format this URL in my Ajax call when I also need to append the ?jsonp=myCallback as well?

I want information such as "averageItemLevel":562 found on that link, but can't use the URL:

```
"url":"http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/aerie-peak/Eldershield?fields=items?jsonp=myCallback"
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution involving the ?'s in the URL or something, but I have tried several variations and am clearly missing something.

I appreciate everyone's time, and thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You separate parameters using `&`, not `?`.

Comment: ^^^and jquery will automagically do that for you if you use the `data` parameter when setting the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `data` option to specify parameters in the AJAX call. jQuery will add them to the URL properly.

```
        $.ajax({
            "url":"http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/aerie-peak/Eldershield?jsonp=myCallback",
            "type":"GET",
            "data": { fields: "items" },
            "dataType":"jsonp",
            "contentType":"application/json",
            "jsonpCallback":"myCallback",
            "success":function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert(data.name);
            }               
        })
```

If you want to do it yourself, the URL should be:

```
http://us.battle.net/api/wow/character/aerie-peak/Eldershield?fields=items&jsonp=myCallback
```

`?` is used to delimit the parameters from the script name, and `&` is used to delimit each parameter.

Comment: Barmar, You've certainly managed to clear up my error and I'll certainly flag this answer as correct.  How do I go one step deeper in to the JSON data?  It works when I alert any of the first key/value combos (such as name), but when I try to alert something within "items", such as equippedItemLevel, I still don't see a result?,  (i tried alert(data.items.averageItemLevel))

Comment: I don't see `equippedItemLevel` in the result. I see `data.items.averageItemLevelEquipped`.

Comment: On a scale from 0 to 100, you are a 95 and I'm a 6.  I shall name my next child Barmar.  Thanks again for your time and help, and I'm sorry they allow young punks like me on here!  I'm learning!

Answer (score 1):

Format your query string in a proper way [Read This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and to answer your question [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651656/passing-multiple-parameters-with-ajax-url). 
In short, you start adding parameters by using `?` and then build them up and continue adding using `&`. When I read the url,I read **`?`** as **`where`** and **`&`** as **`and`**

**DOMAIN.come/pagename.ext`?`para1=val1`&`para2=val2`&`para3=val3**

But since you are going to do an AJAX request with JQuery, it allows you to add all parameters to the ajax object and it will build it for you using `data` parameter.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
        "url":"http://exampleSite.com/request.php",
        "type":"GET",
        "data": {"para1":"val1","para2","val2", "para3","val3" },
        "dataType":"jsonp",
        "success":function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }               
    })
```

and if you check your Developer Tool you will find that the browser made this request

```
http://exampleSite.com/request.php?para1=val1&para2=val2&para2=val2
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammed, summed up very well for someone at my level.

Comment: @Bonedancer Glad to help. Bear in mind that you can also use the 'data' in ajax object to make POST requests and jquery will form if for you.