# AJAX POST request using JQuery with body and URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm learning how to make AJAX calls with JQuery and one thing I was wondering if it's possible to do is include some data as URL parameters and other data in the post body. For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/myURL',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})
```

but in addition to the JSON data which is being sent in the POST request body, I'd like to include URL parameters. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You _can_ include them in the `url: '/myURL?p=1&a=2'` but this would be a mix of `POST` and `GET`. Why not just include them in the data body? Duplicate of [Passing multiple parameters with $.ajax url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651656/passing-multiple-parameters-with-ajax-url) ?

Answer (score 5):

You would be able to include the variables in the url portion of your code. For example

```
var example1 = "some_information";

$.ajax({
  url: '/myURL',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})
```

would become

```
var example1 = "some_information";

$.ajax({
  url: '/myURL?var1=example1',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})
```

You may need to put quotes around the example1 variable to ensure it doesn't break when there are spaces in the url.

Answer (score 1):

You can send parameters normally in the URL as in the get request 
either using `?` and `&`

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/myURL?data2=' + data2 + '&data3=' + data3,
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})
```

or by set them between `/`

```
$.ajax({
 url: '/myURL/' + data2 + '/' + data3,
 type: 'POST',
 data: JSON.stringify(data),
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
})
```

The way of including the parameters on the URL will depends of the way you receive/parse them on the server side, however this is not considered as good practice for the post request.